Export and Import the specific GPG key only
I am using Linux 24.04 and have multiple GPG keys on same machine. I want to tell Git my Project A to use GPG A, Project B will use GPG B, e.g. Each project has Makefile as following:
show_gpg_info:
    @echo "\nYour current GPG list:"
    @gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long
    @echo "Please choose one GPG ID and input the corresponding information to continue."

choose_gpg_key:
    @read -p "Choose email: " input_email;
    @read -p "GPG ID: " input_gpg_key;
    @read -p "Your name: " input_full_name;

export_import_gpg_keys:
    @gpg --export $(input_email) > gpg-public.key
    @gpg --import gpg-public.key
    @gpg --export-secret-key $(input_email) > gpg-private.key
    @gpg --import gpg-private.key

When I run the Makefile, I want to export one key for one project but in fact, it always export and import all keys existed in my machine. It seems $(input_email) provided empty value but when I echo variables, they were right value recorded. Any idea?

The question is not about git, but about gpg, make and makefile. My advice is to fix tags.

I fixed tag as you suggested

What target are you calling?

There are several issues here. Confusion between shell variables and make variables, the (wrong) assumption that different recipes or different recipe lines can exchange values using variables... Make is not a scripting language. Why do you try to do this with make while a scripting language would be a better choice?

I wanna create a Makefile to install with single command line when a new developer join my team. When he/she finish cloning my project repository, then run make install. During project installation, it will ask for GPG key existed on their machine to sign for their commits.

Then you could write a shell script and execute it in a make recipe. Considering that you apparently do not know much about make it would probably be simpler and safer. By the way, what is the point of exporting gpg keys and re-importing them?

To answer your question about what is wrong: in your second rule input_email, input_gpg_key and input_full_name are shell variable. As each line is executed in a separate shell these variables disappear immediately after they have been assigned. In the third rule $(input_email) is the expansion of make variable input_email that has probably never been assigned. So, it expands as the empty string. Even if you were using $${input_email} it would not work because this line is executed in another separate shell where this variable has not been assigned.
